# Code to run after all files are installed with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I got the following little function which I need to call after all files of the `[Files]` section have been copied

```pascal
procedure DllAfterInstall(platform: Integer);
begin
    if not installDriver(platform) then
                MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:installDriverFail}'), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

where `installDriver(platform)` is an external function to one of my dll's.

As soon as I try to call the `DllAfterInstall` function in the `[Run]` section like

```
Filename: "{code:DllAfterInstall}"; Parameters: 0; Check: not IsWin64
```

I got the error

> Invalid prototype for 'DllAfterInstall'

So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or maybe is there another way to call a `*.dll` after all files have been copied? The `*.dll` function should only be called once so `AfterInstall` is no option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call your code from [`CurStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) when `CurStep` is `ssPostInstall`:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Log('Post install');
    DllAfterInstall(platform);
  end;
end;
```

You also need to provide an actual value to the `platform` parameter of the function.