# Inno Setup - Running script does not work in the first attempt for a new machine

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have created a simple executable (.exe) file using **Inno Setup Compiler 6.0.2** for installing a Windows application.

The .exe file calls a  vbscript **"Setup.vbs"** that unzips "Application.zip" file and updates environment variables.

When I run the .exe file **for the first time on a new machine, the .vbs file doesn't get executed**. But, from second attempt onwards it works fine. Is this a known issue or is there any solution for this?

Here is the code snippet that I am using to call run .vbs file

```pascal
[Code]
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
    var ResultCode: integer;
begin
    ShellExec('',ExpandConstant('{app}\{#MyAppExeName}'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
end;
```

---

## Update

I want the .vbs to execute before the installation. So, I tried `ExtractTemporaryFile`, still I am facing the same issue. Not sure what is is wrong with the code below.

```pascal
#define MyAppExeName "Setup.vbs"

[Files]
Source: "..\Application\Installation_Setup\Setup.vbs"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Code]
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
var
  ResultCode: integer;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('{#MyAppExeName}');
  ShellExec('',ExpandConstant('{app}\{#MyAppExeName}'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew ! Being new to stackoverflow, having tough time posting code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PrepareToInstall`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=PrepareToInstall) happens **before** installation. As you execute a file that is installed, it does not exist yet at the time you call it.

Possible solutions

- Execute the script after installation from [`CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged):
  [Code to run after all files are installed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32777470/850848)

  Or you can use `[Run]` section:
  [Executing installed batch file in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40651165/850848)
- If you need to execute the script before installation (I do not think that's your case), use [`ExtractTemporaryFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfile).
- For extracting ZIP, you do not need VBS script, you can do that directly from Inno Setup code.
  [How to get Inno Setup to unzip a file it installed (all as part of the one installation process)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6065364/850848#40706549)

Comment: Thanks for the response ! 

I couldnt paste my code snippet here in the comments section.  Hence, have posted an answer seeking some clarification.

Comment: `ExtractTemporaryFile('{#MyAppExeName}');`  and `ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#MyAppExeName}')`  instead of `ExpandConstant('{tmp}\{#MyAppExeName}') ` worked for me. Thanks !